# How to define end in objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, definition, undefined

```
OSStatus SetupBuffers(BG_FileInfo *inFileInfo)
{
int numBuffersToQueue = kNumberBuffers;
UInt32 maxPacketSize;
UInt32 size = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
// we need to calculate how many packets we read at a time, and how big a buffer we need
// we base this on the size of the packets in the file and an approximate duration for      each buffer

// first check to see what the max size of a packet is - if it is bigger
// than our allocation default size, that needs to become larger
OSStatus result = AudioFileGetProperty(inFileInfo->mAFID,   kAudioFilePropertyPacketSizeUpperBound, &size, &maxPacketSize);
AssertNoError("Error getting packet upper bound size", end);
bool isFormatVBR = (inFileInfo->mFileFormat.mBytesPerPacket == 0 || inFileInfo-   >mFileFormat.mFramesPerPacket == 0);

CalculateBytesForTime(inFileInfo->mFileFormat, maxPacketSize, 0.5/*seconds*/,  &mBufferByteSize, &mNumPacketsToRead);

// if the file is smaller than the capacity of all the buffer queues, always load it at  once
if ((mBufferByteSize * numBuffersToQueue) > inFileInfo->mFileDataSize)
inFileInfo->mLoadAtOnce = true;

if (inFileInfo->mLoadAtOnce)
{
UInt64 theFileNumPackets;
size = sizeof(UInt64);
result = AudioFileGetProperty(inFileInfo->mAFID, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount,   &size, &theFileNumPackets);
       AssertNoError("Error getting packet count for file", end);***>>>>this is where xcode says undefined<<<<***

      mNumPacketsToRead = (UInt32)theFileNumPackets;
      mBufferByteSize = inFileInfo->mFileDataSize;
      numBuffersToQueue = 1;
   }
```

//Here is the exact error

> label 'end' used but not defined
>        I have that error twice

Comment: Tip: Indent all your code with 4 space so it's nicely formatted. This will improve readability and the chance of getting a proper answer. - Oh, and ask a proper question as well, dumping code doesn't do much, we're not compilers, you know.

Comment: While I believe Ariejan missed the part of your code where you annotated the error, it's best to help us help you by describing the problem in the body of your question, separate from the code you provide. Also, please post the *exact* error message you receive.

Comment: @DanielsCaleb0, Uhm, the only place I can find `AssertNoError` is here in [Technical Note TN2113.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2005/tn2113.html) And it has a completely different format. `AssertNoError(theError, "couldn't unregister the ABL");`  Where is `AssertNoError` defined?

Comment: @Stephen: I thought that too until I saw another call near the beginning. Curious that it has a problem with the second use of the function but not the first.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: I think you should make that an answer, because it's probably right.  You might also want to query where "end" comes from.  BTW I also came across this reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Listings/iPublicUtility_CADebugMacros_h.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009222-iPublicUtility_CADebugMacros_h-DontLinkElementID_10

Comment: Thanks guys yeah Stephan Furlani is right.  i imagine i didnt define the whole section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, the only place I can find `AssertNoError` is here in [Technical Note TN2113](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2005/tn2113.html). And it has a completely different format. `AssertNoError(theError, "couldn't unregister the ABL");` Where is `AssertNoError` defined?

User @Jeremy P mentions [this document as well.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Listings/iPublicUtility_CADebugMacros_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009222-iPublicUtility_CADebugMacros_h-DontLinkElementID_10)

Comment: Actually, the code snippet is from the file SoundEngine.cpp in cocos2D, which also defines an AssertNoError macro with the format used here.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the SoundEngine.cpp source that the snippet comes from, you'll see it's defined on the very next line:

```
end:
    return result;
```

It's a label that execution jumps to when there's an error.